# speed the image download time

Tags: javascript, performance, http, parallel-processing

In our application,we provide the online map like google map:
show the map tiles in a div(the container),when user drag/move the container,new map tiles(in fact,they are images) will be downloaded.

However unlike google map,we provide more than one layers in the container,for exmaple,in the following tile:

[image]

It is just one image,but in our case,it maybe more than 5 transprant images overlayed together.

So,once user drag or move the container,we will download 5 times amount of images than before. Which will cause the "mouse drag operation" so slowly,so I wonder if there is any way to improve it?

In my opinion this is caused by the http Parallel Downloads. In common,we will download about 6(6 tiles in the current map view,see the image below)*5(layers)=30 images per operation by user.

This is a big requrement.

I read this paper:
[Performance Research, Part 4: Maximizing Parallel Downloads in the Carpool Lane](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/)

The author provide a way "using additional aliases" to increase the parallel downloads in our pages,it seems a good idea.

But our application run in the intranet network without the Internet,user often browse the site use this url :

```
http://servername/app
```

And Our tiles are saved at: `http://servername/app/tiles/...../xx.png`

So I do not know if we can add aliases like :

```
http://img1.servername/app/tiles/...../xx.png
http://img2.servername/app/tiles/...../xx.png ?
```

I do not think so. :(

So in my case,any idea to improvement the Performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the load to the server side for a bit by making something that just merges those tiles.

For example your serverside program would exist at http://www.servername/app/tiles/gettile/?12&13&14 and just return the merged result of tile 12 13 and 14.

Comment: Generally,we caculate the image url according the current map view,then add the image in the right place,but if we request more than one tiles in one request,how do we layout these tiles? Also,add something in the serverside,I wonder if it will take the extra time rather than we request the static .png file?

Answer (score 0):

Download the images for the next squares in all directions, while user is not moving the map, so you have them pre-downloaded.
Download only first layer and display it, then download the next and displayed, etc.
Generally, intraned should be fast. Make sure the images themself are optimized.
Check with your system administrators if the subdomains are really not possible.
And why you are using 6 tiles - check if you can do them with one, you will save http requests. Also, ensure proper caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use domain names in your intranet assuming the computers in the intranet goes through a DNS server. On the DNS server, you can create all the alias domains and point them to the same server. 
If no DNS server, you can open up the HOSTS file on each PC and put those aliases and point to the same server IP.
If that's not an option, then you should make the 5 transparent layers a single image. So, for a certain coordinate, instead of loading 5 transparent images, you load one transparent image that has the 5 images combined. You can either do it statically by running some tool that combines the images of the same coordinate into one file or you can do dynamically by hitting some http handler that merges the 5 images and emits as one file.